# Put multi-model multi-run ensemble into xarray Dataset

Tags: python-xarray

I have multi-model multi-run ensemble data, i.e. a model ensemble in which each model has individual runs as well. I would like to be able to address the runs both by model (i.e. get all ensemble members that belong to a specific model) and by member (i.e. get a mean over specific/all runs, no matter which model). `model` should therefore be the model name and `member` just an arbitrary number or ID.

My draft look like this:

```
ds = xr.Dataset(
        {'some_var': (['time', 'model'], some_data)},
        coords={'time': pd.date_range(from_date, to_date),
                'model': (['model', ], some_data.shape[1] * [model_name])})
```

however, I don't manage to make a `member` variable/coordinate such that I could do both:

```
ds.sel(dict(model='model_a', member=0))  # select member 0 from model a
```

and

```
ds.sel(time=0).some_var.mean()  # calulate mean of whole ensemble at time 0
```

I've tried to make a `member` variable that depends on the `model` coordinate, but then I can't select for it.

I refrained from using groups for individual models, because then making statistics over the whole ensemble gets diffcult.
How would this be organized in the file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think it was easier than I thought. It should be something like:

```
ds = xr.Dataset({'some_var': (['time', 'member', 'model'], some_3D_var)},
                       coords={'member': (['member', ], np.arange(some_3D_var.shape[1])),
                               'model': (['model', ], ['model_name']),
                               'time': (['time', ], pd.date_range(from_date, to_date)),
                               })
```

Like this it should be possible to apply both selections to the dataset.